# Reshape matrix and transform it to data frame keeping track of original row and column index

Tags: r

I have a large n by m matrix that I would like to transform into a (n * m) by 3 data frame (my matrix is something like 1400 by 800). The first column of the data frame should contain the matrix row index. The second column should contain the matrix column index, and the third column of the data frame should contain the value of each cell from the matrix.

I solved this problem with a for loop, but I don't think this is the best way. I was wondering if there is an easier or more efficient way to acchieve the same final data frame.

Here is a small reproducible code of my solution that I would like to improve.

```r
mtx <- array(rep(rnorm(12)), dim = c(4,3))

df <- expand.grid(rnum = 1:4, cnum = 1:3)
df$cell <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$cell[i] <- mtx[df$rnum[i],df$cnum[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `row`/`col` to get row and column value for each value in the matrix and collapse the matrix into a vector to get the actual value and `cbind` all of them together.

```
cbind.data.frame(rnum = c(row(mtx)), cnum = c(col(mtx)), cell = c(mtx))

#   rnum cnum       cell
#1     1    1 -1.2070657
#2     2    1  0.2774292
#3     3    1  1.0844412
#4     4    1 -2.3456977
#5     1    2  0.4291247
#6     2    2  0.5060559
#7     3    2 -0.5747400
#8     4    2 -0.5466319
#9     1    3 -0.5644520
#10    2    3 -0.8900378
#11    3    3 -0.4771927
#12    4    3 -0.9983864
```

---

A trick we can use with `which` is to find a condition which is always `TRUE`, use `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row and column index and `cbind` the values same as above.

```
cbind.data.frame(which(mtx > 0 | mtx < 0, arr.ind = TRUE), cell = c(mtx))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
mtx <- array(rep(rnorm(12)), dim = c(4,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mtx)
#   Var1 Var2      value
#1     1    1 -1.2070657
#2     2    1  0.2774292
#3     3    1  1.0844412
#4     4    1 -2.3456977
#5     1    2  0.4291247
#6     2    2  0.5060559
#7     3    2 -0.5747400
#8     4    2 -0.5466319
#9     1    3 -0.5644520
#10    2    3 -0.8900378
#11    3    3 -0.4771927
#12    4    3 -0.9983864
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1234)
mtx <- array(rep(rnorm(12)), dim = c(4,3))
```